# I create a channel in Office 365 video but the site collection never shows up

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I work for a K12 school district and I've been assigned to help setup Office 365 video for our school to use. I've read several articles about Office 365 video and they all mention that when you create a channel, a corresponding site collection should be created within SharePoint.

So as the admin I created several channels over a week ago, that still exist and are working, but the site collections for these channels have yet to appear. In our list of site collections we have the main portals/hub and then we also have portals/District Videos and portals/community. I've also noticed that editing the O365 video's homepage settings don't seem to take effect either. The spotlight and channels settings have been edited but the changes don't apply.

Our SharePoint Online deployment was setup about a year ago as kind of a demo/test experience and so we haven't really been using most of the features it provides until now. So I was just curious to find out why our Office 365 video setup doesn't seem to be acting normal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, to me it seems like the best you can do is to open a ticket with Microsoft support. As you say, the expected behaviour (at least historically) has been for each channel to show up as a site collection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Robert. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a new change that Microsoft made. I'll contact Microsoft support next week and see what I can find. The last thing I want to do is create dozens of channels and then find out that something was wrong when we created them.

Comment: I had it happen one time, I just deleted the channel and recreated it and everything was fine.

Comment: I'll just have to create a ticket with Microsoft I guess. I tried deleting the old video channels and creating a new one and it still isn't building a matching site collection.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the screenshot of my channel, Name- "Office 365".

To download the videos in channels replace this link with your portal name and channel.

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/portals/ChannelName/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx.
```

Here I am trying as, `https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/portals/office-365/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`
Note: If you have space in your channel name replace with "-".

Below is the screen shot of my channel site contents,

[image: Below is the screen shot of my channel site contents]
Open Videos library and download videos,

NOTE; EVERYTIME YOUR CHANNEL NAME WILL NOT BE SAME IN SITE COLLECTION URL. IF THE ABOVE STEPS DOES'NT WORK TRY THESE STEPS,

Here my channel name is marketing channel videos but my site collection url says "Marketing-channel", below are the steps to fins your site collection url,

```
GO TO OFFICE 365 PORTAL SETTINGS, " " " "https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_layouts/15/videoportalsettings.aspx"
```

GO TO > SPOTLIGHT
UNDER SPOTLIGHT CHANNELS DROP DOWN SELECT THE CHANNEL WHICH YOU WANT TO SEE THE SITE CONTENTS AND DOWNLOAD VIDEOS.
Now this spotlight channel will be shown in Main site " HUB" site settings. Go to URL `"https://COMPANY.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" then go to "HUB SETTINGS"`

[image]
here you will see the site collection as highleted in the below image, "/portals/Marketing-Channel/pVid " 
Now replace this url in `"https://company.sharepoint.com/portals/ChannelName/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx".`  Like  `"//company.sharepoint.com/portals/Marketing-Channel/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx.`"

you will go to site contents, from here you should be able to download videos from videos library.